# .htaccess redirect based on folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I need help with .htaccess Rewrite rules.

I have a API which can be accessed over `http://api.my.domain/products/all` which is working fine and is returning result.

I would like to redirect users coming to `http://api.my.domain/admin` to admin folder.But it is not working with current rules.

I have added this to `.htaccess` but it is not working correctly for `admin` folder.

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-F

RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^admin admin/index.php [QSD,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSD,L]
```

This is the result I get when I enter `http://api.my.domain/admin` and is breaking all my php redirects:

> http://api.drezga.hr/admin/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/admin/admin/checklogin.php

Can someone, please, tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have spent hours and I can't see it.

Comment: You've tagged the question `nginx` - how does this fit into things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aside:* If `/admin` is a physical directory then you should be requesting `/admin/` (with a trailing slash) to begin with, otherwise Apache/mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-F
>
> RewriteCond %{Request_Filename} !-d
>
> RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
> RewriteRule ^admin admin/index.php [QSD,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
> RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSD,L]
> ```

The first two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) are being applied *incorrectly* to the first rule only. They need to apply to the last rule (the rewrite to `public/index.php`) then the rewrite to `admin/index.php` is not necessary (this should be handled by the `DirectoryIndex`).

There's no need for the `QSD` flag since you are checking that the query string is already empty - there is no query string to discard!

You should probably be using the `-f` operator on the *condition*, not `-F` (which uses subrequests and is consequently less efficient).

Try the following instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Optimisation (prevent additional filesystem check)
RewriteRule ^public/index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
```

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` directive prevents requests for `/admin/` being passed to `public/index.php`.

The additional `RewriteRule` at the end is to rewrite requests for the root directory, which would otherwise be omitted because of the *condition* mentioned above. This could be avoided by extending the `DirectoryIndex` directive instead, although this could change the behaviour if you have other directories that need to be accessible (or should not be routed to `public/index.php`). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /public/index.php
```

Comment: That is it! Working like a charm! Thank you so much, I have spent hours trying to figure it out. You saved my day!